# getting the last modified date of a html file

Tags: html, date

how can i figure out the last modified date of a html file im importing into my web app?

The html file is on another server and different users can make updates, when i retrieve the page i want to be able see when it was last updated so i can label the updated date on my homepage. I

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you are using HTTP to retrieve the page.

In that case you can use the HEAD method of HTTP to get the header data of the file. (See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html, 9.4)

Then you can check the "Last-Modified" header of the response. (See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html, 14.29)

In case of some caching mechanism (proxy, browser caching) it might be necessary to include "Cache-Control: must-revalidate" in the request header. (See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html, 14.9.4)

Answer (score 7):

Use the `document.lastModified` Javascript property.

quirksmode has a nice function to format the date too: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/lastmod.html

Comment: I'm wondering, how does the `document.lastModified` JavaScript property actually work? I didn't know JavaScript could see when you last edited the file. Do you know how it works?

Comment: @Nathan It uses the `Last-Modified` header.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [Last-Modfied Header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) from the response headers.

> The Last-Modified entity-header field indicates the date and time at which the origin server believes the variant was last modified.

```
   Last-Modified  = "Last-Modified" ":" HTTP-date
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
document.write(document.lastModified);
// -->
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some proposed meta tag keys representing Dublin Core values that may be used. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14893974/895245