# Is there a standardized (meta?) tag for the date of a website?

Tags: html, date, seo, meta-tags

One thing that search engines really suck with is the date when a website was created. You know the problem: You search for some CSS or JavaScript problem and Google returns a ton of results from 2002 explaining how to fix the problem in IE 5.5 and Netscape 4.6 while the helpful articles are buried on Page 3.

Anyway, I just wonder if there is a standardized or at least generally accepted tag or meta tag that I can put on my own pages to indicate the date they were created?

Not that it helps filtering out the old crap out of search results (especially since the people at #1 with their 2002 articles have zero incentive to change), but I'd just like to do my part :P

Comment: That's a bloody good question, and I don't know the answer, but it'd be excellent if there was an existing or emerging "standard", perhaps using some extant microformat, that search engines and other content portals could intercept and display to help end users make better decisions about content. Of course, there's "Last Modified" and so on, but that's not quite the same thing, since it's more of a cache invalidation timestamp.

Comment: Brilliant. The internet would be just so much better with this. [/me remembers countless times when skimming a webpage for anything which looks like a date]

Comment: You know that if you click 'More search tools' on the sidebar on the Google search results page it will let you search for articles in the last day/week/month/year?  Though in many cases it looks to me like the dates in question are 'when Google crawled it' rather than 'when it was created' it does seem to work really well with blog posts.

Comment: @robertc Yes, Google *tries* to find the date of websites through a number of ways, but it's wildly inaccurate, so I'm wondering if there is a standard/accepted/better way.

Comment: Could be interesting to ask that at the Google webmaster central. Wonder whether they have an official stand on that ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There have been a few [WHATWG Meta Extension proposals](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions), referenced in the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#concept-meta-extensions) which could cater for the creation date of a page.

***"Accepted"* Proposals**
[`dcterms.available`](http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-terms/#terms-available) - The date the resource became available.
[`dcterms.created`](http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-terms/#terms-created) - The creation date of the resource.
[`dcterms.dateAccepted`](http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-terms/#terms-dateAccepted) - The date the resource was accepted.
[`dcterms.submitted`](http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-terms/#terms-dateSubmitted) - The date the resource was submitted.
[`dcterms.issued`](http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-terms/#terms-issued) - The publication date of a resource.

**Related *"Accepted"* Proposals**
[`dcterms.modified`](http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-terms/#terms-modified) - The modification date of a resource
[`dcterms.valid`](http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-terms/#terms-valid) - The validity of the resource.

There are a couple of "incomplete proposals" which haven't been accepted due to a lack of documentation (such as `created`).

I don't believe [Hangy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4576005/1317805) of `dc.date` (now `dcterms.date`) would be relevant here as, as far as I'm lead to believe, the date of this is the date associated with the resource. For example, if the resource was a discussion about the Battle of Hastings in 1066, the `dcterms.date` could be set to 1066. The same could also be said for `icas.datetime`.

Answer (score 6):

It's not a standard, but I remember reading on A List Apart about [RDFa](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/introduction-to-rdfa/). It, or other forms of microformatting, may just be the solution you're looking for.

Comment: It seems that Google supports it, so that may indeed be the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose the [`DC.date`](http://dublincore.org/documents/dcq-html/) tag could be used for that. The Dublin Core metadata is relatively established and well known.

You could also mark your websites with [XMDP](http://gmpg.org/xmdp/), which has a date tag that is supposed to be the date of the last modification.

Comment: Interesting. I know Dublin Core for Media Files (I think Adobe is pushing it heavily), haven't seen it for Websites yet. Will have a look.

Answer (score 3):

You could try RDFa (or Microformats) as James and hangy have suggested, Google supports them through a feature called [Rich Snippets](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170).  Use the Rich Snippets Testing Tool to see how it's working - for example it does pick up the `dtreviewed` and the rating from [one of my blog posts](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.boogdesign.com%2Fb2evo%2Findex.php%2Flws-may-accessible-design%3Fblog%3D2&view=) which is marked up with [hreview](http://microformats.org/wiki/hreview).

Answer (score 3):

For marking content, you can go the HTML5 route of [microdata](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=176035).

I'm struggling with the same question - google can figure out dates on some content on my site, but not others. I want to help it, so it can always get the date on the article.

I'm trying a combination of the "dc.date" metatag suggested above, and marking up the timestamp that appears on the page using microdata.

Google's example of how to mark up your timestamps using microdata is:

```
<time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2009-10-15T19:00-08:00">15 October 2009, 7PM</time>
```

Comment: Only this is useful when you put the date (and time) in the page somewhere. I don't think you can put that tag in the `<head>`, can you?

Comment: yes meta ist also possible