# Display a file's date/time using HTML or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a homepage for the workstations in my office that has links to our most frequently accessed websites.

It is kept on our server, but is copied to each workstation as a user logs in, so if the server is down, everyone can at least still function independently.

Right now, I manually change a line of text in the HTML code itself to show that date I last updated the file.

I would like to have the HTML's modified date (or creation date) automatically displayed instead.

I would also like to have the date and time shown of the master file on the server so that if I've made an update during the day, the user will know and can manually update their local copy, instead of waiting until the next time they log in.

Here's a sample output to illustrate the end result:

> WORKSTATION HOMEPAGE
>
> Current Version | Latest Version
>
> March 1, 2014 | March 13, 2014
>
> LINKS etc.

I've found some reference to this pertaining to PHP servers, since this is just for our internal use only, and we're all using IE 8+. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: doesn't matter what browser you're using. if you want the date-of-generation embedded in the file, you'll have to do that at the time you do the file copying - if you look at the file times on the machine it's being loaded from, you'll get the times the copy was made, not the time of the original file on the server.

Comment: I figured as much - but then the local copy would have a newer date then the server copy, which still accomplishes the goal of knowing if an update is available. The real trick is the code/script to have it read and display the file date.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204010/getting-the-last-modified-date-of-a-html-file